# Wordpress Custom Fields Value update through a Script

Tags: wordpress, custom-fields

Is there any way that i can change the value of the Custom Field (of wordpress) through php script??i don't want to change the value through the Admin Panel.i tried searching the wp_postmeta table inside database but i didn't find any.

P.S: I am using wordpress 3.4 version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `update_post_meta($post_id, $meta_key, $meta_value, $prev_value)` function to update the custom field from your php scripts.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_post_meta